# Ошибка "resource style/Theme.ViewApp not found" при запуске приложения

Tags: android, android-manifest

Ошибка:

> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\pkkpk\AndroidStudioProjects\nezabivayka\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:18: error: resource style/Theme.ViewApp (aka com.example.nezabivayka:style/Theme.ViewApp) not found.
> error: failed processing manifest.'

Код:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.viewapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ViewApp">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: у вас пишет что не находит ресурс темы, `android:theme="@style/Theme.ViewApp"`. Он у вас есть в стилях? попробуйте `Clean Project -> Rebuild`

Comment: покажите, объявлен ли у вас в файле `styles.xml` стиль `Theme.ViewApp`